# What does "Stack Exchange" refer to?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-history

The Computer Science/software site is called *Stack Overflow*. That has a natural meaning for that field. The more general site is called *Stack Exchange*. What does that refer to?

Answer (score 8):

I believe since Stack Overflow was the first site in the exchange the 'Stack' just comes from there for familliarity/branding. Exchange as a suffix come comes from the generic term 'knowledge exchange', which Jason Calacanis explained to Joel and Jeff in [Podcast #56](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-56/), half a year before the launch of Stack Exchange 1.0.

Comment: Good educated guess becomes hard-facts concrete answer.  Well done to both of you! :) **PLUS ONE**